# How is this form bound?

Tags: ms-access-2010

We are working with an MS Access Database (2010) that is a front-end to a SQL Server database.

One of the programmers has created a form bound to a linked table.

My problem is this:

All of the controls are unbound, and yet they are always filled with data from the query.  How can this be?  I don't really like it.  I wonder if it is some kind of form created from a query made by some wizard?

**[update]**

I discover that if I remove the `Record Source` from the form that all of the controls dissappear and I have only a table view!

What is this "thing" called?

This isn't the way I want it to work; can I convert it to a normal form or do I have to rebuild it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was not a real form.  I still haven't figured out how to duplicate this.  If I can figure it out I'll post back here.

But I think it is one of those Access quickie-wizard-made things where it is really a query but with a form view.  So when I removed the record source, there was no query fields to convert into controls, so they disappeared.

I ended up creating a new form and copying all the controls from the query-view-form to the real form.  Then I copied all the vba code.  Then I hooked the new form up to the original query.

It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

The form's VBA possibly calls an ADO or DAO recordset via ODBC to SQL Server database and attaches it to Form's RecordSource or leaves form unbound and sets values to each control corresponding to fields in recordset. View the code behind form in its VBA module. Alternatively, a pass-through query may be ran and bound to form.

This is a tougher route in connecting frontend to backend systems as you must bypass all of Access' default features, commands, and functionality. Using unbound forms, developer must create custom update, insert, save, and delete events for record management; validation logic for data entry; and constant cursor calls depending on form interaction. But in a sense this mirrors how software and web apps are built. HTML/PHP pages, Java or Python scripts, R data frames are empty designed ("unbound") shells until data is retrieved from a database source called by a connection.

An easier approach is to link the SQL Server backend tables and bound them to Access forms. Linked tables are  available like any local table and can be used in any context (forms, queries, reports, macros,  modules). No need for extensive code to call an ODBC connection every time form opens or events trigger and then customized functions thereafter.

Comment: So the controls are auto-populated by the fields in the query?

Comment: Again, check the VBA behind the form. See if an ODBC or local recordset is being called to the form's recordsource in an OnOpen, OnLoad, or OnCurrent event. If so, controls will be unbound during design view. Recordsets can be a table from external database or query from local database.